# after installing MySql Workbench why i can't login to phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have been working with php and I use phpmyadmin for database.Then I installed mysql workbench for working with mysql. But now  phpmyadmin is not working.I get the error like,

> #2002 - No such file or directory — The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).
>
> mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory

Comment: Operating system/distribution? Tell us more about your environment and which steps you have done.

Comment: Restart the mysql and try again